# Casting a SuperClass Java

Tags: java, casting, clone, subclass

I have three classes:

```
public abstract class X{
   ....
}

public class Y extends X{
    clone(){}
      .....
}

public class Z extends X{
   clone(){}
   .....
}
```

I have a `Set<X> set` which includes Z or Y objects. What if i want to clone a certain element of the set, do i need to use ifs?

```
for(X x:set){
   if(x.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Y")){
       Y n = (Y) x
       n.clone();
   }
}
```

I want to know if there is a simpler way to do this

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you add an abstract method to the X-class? Like `public abstract void clone();`? Then you can just do `x.clone();` in your loop without casting, and it will use the overridden `clone`-method of the Z and Y classes.

Comment: `if (x.getClass() == Y.class)` is simpler, and more robust - there can be many classes called `Y`, but you can only cast one of them with `(Y)`. But you might also find that `x instanceof Y` is easier too - it is not *exactly* the same - this also matches subclasses of `Y`.

Comment: As Kevin said, if your main intent is to call `clone()`, you should add an abstract method `clone()`. Then, inside your loop, you won't need to cast your object to your child class.

Comment: But clone needs to return an Object, how can i implement clone with void?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to clone `Y` objects, yes using an `if` is probably the easiest way here and you should use `instanceof`:

```
for(X x:set){
   if(x instanceof Y)){
       Y n = (Y) x
       n.clone();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the class X implements Cloneable. Then just call clone() on the object by making use of **instanceof** as suggested.

Comment: OP asked for cloning "a certain element". Maybe you would like to edit your answer?